# how to validate entry in a xml file in maven?

Tags: maven

I'd like to ask if it is possible to validate entry (some string, like the jsp page file name) in one xml file in the project in maven or chef (either of them)?  Something like I want to query if I include all the jsp file page name entry in abc.xml file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please give more details?

Comment: thanks, JF. for example, I have a couple of jsp page files (a.jsp, b.jsp, c.jsp) and a list.xml file, I want to make sure each jsp page file name(a.jsp, b.jsp, c.jsp) has an entry in list.xml. thanks again.

Comment: Please edit your question (instead of adding comments) and give a clear and complete example.

Comment: Removing the chef tag since this appears unrelated to Chef.